# Azure AKS add node with different Linux OS

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, centos

When using a Kuberenetes service on Azure the nodes are by default built with an Ubuntu image.

I have a use case of wanting to add more nodes but on the az CLI the os-type is only Linux (ubuntu) or Windows.

Is there a way of adding a Node to an existing Kubernetes cluster on Azure that is of different Linux types like CentOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AKS only supports ubuntu at this time, so this is not yet possible